# In what library on Linux are the system calls and how is this library linked to the executable object file that contains the system calls?

Tags: kernel, libraries, dynamic-linking, system-calls, shared-library

I know that the system calls are not in the C standard Library. Is there any library (some sort of a system library) where the system calls are?

If there is such a library how is this library linked to the executable program?

Comment: Most Linux system calls are available via glibc wrappers.

Answer (score 4):

System calls are the API between program or library and the kernel. The implementation of system call is in the kernel. C library wraps the system calls which are CPU-architecture specific and supplies a unified C API so the C code could be moved from one architecture to another.